# I cant figure out why HandleChange doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a project using ReactJS. I can't figure out how to make `handleCountryChange` work. `fetchedData` gets the API of a country data and then `yesterdayfetcheddata` gets the data from yesterday from that api. I am trying to pass the data through a `handleChange` and for some reason only `fetchedData` is recognized and works. Both `fetcheddata` and `yesterdayfetchedData` is exactly the same info just a day apart the code shows that `yesterdayFetchedData` is undefined within `handleCountryChange`.

this is the link to my code

I have posted the sandbox with the full code now

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sky-h1vkl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I think it is hard to follow your example, because the sandbox you sent is not calling the code you want to debug ?

Comment: I have posted the sandbox with the full code now

Comment: Your main is `Hello CodeSandbox`

Comment: Ok i finally got it right sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was only misspelled of variabled ? https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-tdd-tbun0 seems to work fine